# Camera Intent always return result code 0 and Intent data = null

Tags: java, android, camera

```
@Override
public String getFragmentTag() {
    return FleetVideoFragment.class.getSimpleName();
}
private void dispatchTakeVideoIntent() {
    Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    takeVideoIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
            | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(mActivity.getPackageManager()) != null) {
        File mediaFile = null;
        try {
            mediaFile = createVideoFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Handle the error
        }
        if (mediaFile != null) {
            Uri uriFile = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mActivity,
                    "com.tekfirst.practical.fileprovider",  // Use your FileProvider authority
                    mediaFile);
            takeVideoIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriFile);
            takeVideoIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 60);
            takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
            startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA);
        }
    }
}

private File createVideoFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
```

//        String videoFileName = "VIDEO_" + timeStamp + "*";
String videoFileName = "VIDEO*" + bookedOutRA.getId() + "*" + timeStamp + "*";
//        File storageDir = mActivity.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File storageDir = new File(Objects.requireNonNull(mActivity.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)).getAbsolutePath(), "/" + bookedOutRA.getId());
if (!storageDir.exists()) {
storageDir.mkdirs();
}
File video = File.createTempFile(
videoFileName,  /* prefix */
".mp4",         /* suffix */
storageDir      /* directory */
);

```
    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    getmCurrentPath = video.getAbsolutePath();
    return video;
}
```

I am recording video using default camera but its result is always canceled in latest android devices but in old devices its working. OUTPUT_EXTRA is not working

Comment: Your problem may be the camera app on that particular device. Camera apps are buggy and do not always properly honor `Intent` actions like `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE`.

Comment: So what can be the solution?

Comment: Apologize to the user. Or, test your app with some third-party camera apps and [give the user a chooser](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/16/action-image-capture-android-r.html) -- if you have the problem again, apologize to the user and suggest that they install one of those third-party camera apps. Or, stop using `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` and use CameraX or some other library to record the video yourself.